# Windows - Check if updates are currently being installed

Tags: windows, updates

Is there any way to find out if windows is currently installing updates?
My basic aim is to prevent my programs to perform certain actions or to shut
the pc down while updates are installed.
Is there anything like a bool registry Value or something to check?

Comment: Wouldn't updates continue to install on shutdown anyway? At least on my win7 they do.

Comment: Another function could be to intentionally shut the pc down when the installation is finished